# XMLBeans inst2xsd out of memory error

Tags: java, xml

I run the following command:

```
inst2xsd -design ss -simple-content-types smart -enumerations 10 foo.xml
```

where `foo.xml` is a `500m` file.  I get an `OutOfMemoryError: heapspace`.  How can I pass the correct heapspace arguments on the command line to the `inst2xsd` process?

The following fails:

```
inst2xsd -Xmx1024m -design ss -simple-content-types smart -enumerations 10 foo.xml
```

as well as:

```
inst2xsd -design ss -simple-content-types smart -enumerations 10 foo.xml -Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the `inst2xsd` script in the `xmlbeans-<version>/bin` folder you'll notice that the script doesn't support that.

```
java -classpath "$cp" org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.inst2xsd.Inst2Xsd "$@"
```

Hence, you'll have to alter the script manually.